# How to auto-generate html template in a .cshtml file in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, visual-studio-2022

While doing an ASP.NET project, I created a blank `Details.cshtml` file in Visual Studio 2022. After that, I wanted to auto-generate an html template in the file, like below -

```
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

I thought that typing `html` and then pressing Tab would do the trick (as per the 3:30 timestamp in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWIcHLBnJUg&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVkdrusLaQsfERmL_Jh4XmU&index=21)), however it didn't work. When I searched on the internet, all I got was **VS Code** related results, not even one result talked about **Visual Studio**.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: I dont believe that VS has emmet included like VSCode does out of the box. There is probably an extension you can get to do similar things though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do that just with typing single "!" and pressing TAB :)